# Retrieve a value of a key based on another value(of key) in the list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

question about list of dicts:
"""this is the list of dicts for employees and salaries(pls note this is an example and want this in python memory instead of any other form such as #sql table)"""

```
complete_emp_list = [{'emp_name':'abc','salary':1000}, {'emp_name':'def','salary':2000},{'emp_name':'xyz','salary':3000}]
```

Question: how do I retrieve the salary for a given emp name as part of below query.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT emp_name, {%d}*0.1 AS ret_bonus FROM employee_resigned", salary)
```

Please note I don't want to run this query for all the employees, but only for those in the employee_resigned table (1 or 2 emp) and get the salary from python list(using only list of dicts in the format given above)  (this is very hypothetical example :))

Comment: Is this one question or two? And what do your tables look like?

Answer (score 0):

Just build a dictionary that maps employee names to their salaries:

```
salaries = {d['emp_name']: d['salary'] for d in complete_emp_list}
```

Then it's a simple matter of indexing: `salaries[employee_name]`.

Comment: thanks @a_guest. I am stuck at sql portion as it's failing with syntax check for both these cases, since I need to index on each employee from employee_resigned cursor.execute("SELECT emp_name, {%d}[emp_name]*0.1 AS ret_bonus FROM employee_resigned", salaries)              (or) cursor.execute("SELECT emp_name, {%d}*0.1 AS ret_bonus FROM employee_resigned", salaries[emp_name])

Comment: @kondav I'm not sure what you mean. Could explain in more detail?

Comment: Hi @a_guest, actually index salaries[employee_name] is giving the salary but it is not working when I use it part of sql variable.  for this statement, cursor.execute("SELECT emp_name, {%d}[emp_name]*0.1 AS ret_bonus FROM employee_resigned", salaries), I am receiving error :TypeError: argument 1 must be a string or unicode object: got tuple instead